# How to add events in gridview using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I am using search functionality in gridview using Jquery as mentioned in this article:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Search-GridView-with-Paging-on-TextBox-KeyPress-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx

Search functionality is working perfectly but the problem is there is no events on row click :-(

Is there any way to attach all events(RowCommand, RowDataBound etc.) written in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another row and put a link button there to change the row into edit index so that you can edit a particular row easily